# How to create a custom operator simulating dot (without parentheses)?

Tags: scala

Let's have this code:

```scala
scala> case class Num(n:Int){def inc = Num(n+1)}
defined class Num

scala> implicit class Pipe(n:Num){ def | = n }
defined class Pipe
```

This works:

```scala
scala> (Num(0) |) inc
res7: Num = Num(1)
```

But is it possible to somehow (maybe implicits or macros?) make Scala to run sample bellow in a same way as the code with parentheses without modifying `Num` class?

```scala
scala> Num(0) | inc
<console>:11: error: Num does not take parameters
              Num(0) | inc
                     ^
```

Wanted result is:

```scala
scala> Num(0) | inc | inc
res8: Num = Num(2)
```

---

EDIT:
Here's code that's much closer to the real thing. I hope this is more understandable.

```
object ApplyTroubles2 extends App {

  import GrepOption.GrepOption

  abstract class Builder {
    var parent: Builder = null

    def getOutput: String

    def append(ch: Builder) = { ch.parent = this; ch }

    def echo(s: String) = append(new Echo(s))

    def wc() = append(new Wc())

    def grep(s: String, opts: Set[GrepOption]) = append(new Grep(s, opts))

    def grep(s: String) = append(new Grep(s))
  }

  object MainBuilder extends Builder {
    def getOutput: String = ""

    override def append(ch: Builder): Builder = ch
  }

  class Echo(data: String) extends Builder {
    def getOutput = data
  }

  class Wc() extends Builder {
    def getOutput = parent.getOutput.size.toString
  }

  class Grep(var pattern: String, options: Set[GrepOption]) extends Builder {
    def this(pattern: String) = this(pattern, Set.empty)

    val isCaseInsensitive = options.contains(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)

    if (isCaseInsensitive) pattern = pattern.toLowerCase

    def getOutput = {
      val input = if (isCaseInsensitive) parent.getOutput.toLowerCase else parent.getOutput
      if (input.contains(pattern)) input
      else ""
    }
  }

  object GrepOption extends Enumeration {
    type GrepOption = Value
    val CASE_INSENSITIVE = Value
  }

  object BuilderPimps {
    //    val wc: Builder => Builder = x => x.wc()
    //    def echo(msg: String): Builder => Builder = x => x.echo(msg)
  }

  implicit class BuilderPimps(b: Builder) {
    // as suggested in one answer, should solve calling an apply method
    //    def |(fn: Builder => Builder): Builder = fn(b)

    def | : Builder = b

    def getStringOutput: String = b.getOutput

    def >> : String = getStringOutput
  }

  import MainBuilder._

  // working
  println(echo("xxx").wc().getOutput)
  println(echo("str") getStringOutput)
  println((echo("y") |) wc() getStringOutput)
  println(((((echo("y") |) echo ("zz")) |) wc()) >>)
  println(((echo("abc") |) grep ("b")) >>)
  println((echo("aBc") |) grep("AbC", Set(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)) getStringOutput)

  // not working
  println((echo("yyyy") | wc()) getStringOutput)
  println(echo("yyyy") | wc() getStringOutput)
  println((echo("y")|) grep("y") >>)
  println(echo("x") | grep("x") | wc() >>)
}
```

I realize that wanted operator adds no extra value in terms of functionality, it's supposed to be just a syntactic sugar to make things look nicer (in this case I'm trying to mimic the shell piping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181011/1017211) from Akos Krivachy is pretty close, but since I can't append my complete solution to it I have to create a new separate answer (this feature of SO seems a bit weird to me).

```
object ApplyTroubles2 extends App {

  import GrepOption.GrepOption

  abstract class Builder {
    var parent: Builder = null

    def getOutput: String

    def append(ch: Builder) = { ch.parent = this; ch }

    def echo(s: String) = append(new Echo(s))

    def wc() = append(new Wc())

    def grep(s: String, opts: Set[GrepOption]) = append(new Grep(s, opts))

    def grep(s: String) = append(new Grep(s))
  }

  object MainBuilder extends Builder {
    def getOutput: String = ""

    override def append(ch: Builder): Builder = ch
  }

  class Echo(data: String) extends Builder {
    def getOutput = data
  }

  class Wc() extends Builder {
    def getOutput = parent.getOutput.size.toString
  }

  class Grep(var pattern: String, options: Set[GrepOption]) extends Builder {
    def this(pattern: String) = this(pattern, Set.empty)

    val isCaseInsensitive = options.contains(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)

    if (isCaseInsensitive) pattern = pattern.toLowerCase

    def getOutput = {
      val input = if (isCaseInsensitive) parent.getOutput.toLowerCase else parent.getOutput
      if (input.contains(pattern)) input
      else ""
    }
  }

  object GrepOption extends Enumeration {
    type GrepOption = Value
    val CASE_INSENSITIVE = Value
  }

  // all above is un-touchable (e.g. code of a library I want to pimp out)

  // all bellow are the pimps I wanted
  // (
  //   based on this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181011/1017211]
  //   from Akos Krivachy [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697985/akos-krivachy]
  // )

  object MyBuilder {
    type MyBuilderTransformer = MyBuilder => MyBuilder

    def builderFunc(func: Builder => Builder): MyBuilderTransformer =
      (x: MyBuilder) => {func(x.builder).wrap}

    // methods in original library without parameters can be represented as vals
    val wc: MyBuilderTransformer = builderFunc(_.wc())

    // when it has parameters it must be def, we need to pack params
    def grep(s: String): MyBuilderTransformer = builderFunc(_.grep(s))

    def grep(s: String, ss: Set[GrepOption]): MyBuilderTransformer = builderFunc(_.grep(s, ss))

    // root expression, differs a bit from original, but in this case it's good enough
    def fromString(msg: String): MyBuilder = MyBuilder(MainBuilder.echo(msg))
  }

  // wrapper class
  case class MyBuilder(builder: Builder)

  implicit class BuilderPimps(b: Builder) {
    def wrap = MyBuilder(b)
  }

  implicit class MyBuilderPimps(b: MyBuilder) {
    def |(fn: MyBuilder => MyBuilder): MyBuilder = fn(b)

    def getStringOutput: String = b.builder.getOutput

    def >> : String = getStringOutput
  }

  // this all works (shows how an end user would use this pimps)

  import MyBuilder._

  println(fromString("abc") | wc getStringOutput)
  println(fromString("abc") | wc >>)

  println(fromString("abc") | grep("b") | wc getStringOutput)
  println(fromString("abc") | grep("b") | wc >>)

  println(fromString("abc") | grep("B", Set(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)) | wc getStringOutput)
  println(fromString("abc") | grep("B", Set(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)) | wc >>)

  println(fromString("abc") | grep("y", Set(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)) | wc getStringOutput)
  println(fromString("abc") | grep("y", Set(GrepOption.CASE_INSENSITIVE)) | wc >>)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Postfix vs Infix**

Let's first look at how infix and postfix notation relate to each other. Given your case when you write `Num(0) | inc` then that is equivalent to `Num(0).|(inc)` in postfix notation.

So looking at your desired syntax:

```
Num(0) | inc | inc
```

This will be equivalent to the following in postfix notation:

```
Num(0).|(inc).|(inc)
```

Ok, now that that's clear let's do this!

**The solution**

The `def |` needs to take a parameter, that holds the function it should do. There are two solutions here, either we define a function over `Num` or we define a function over the `Int` the `Num` is actually holding:

```
implicit class Pipe(n:Num){
  def |(fn: (Num) => Num) = fn(n)
  def |(fn: (Int) => Int) = Num(fn(n.n))
}
```

Both would work - you need to choose which one will work best for you.

Now that we have this, we need to define this function. You could put this in `Num`'s companion object (also providing the two differing implementations):

```
object Num {
  val incNum: Num => Num = n => Num(n.n + 1)
  val inc = (i: Int) => i + 1
}
```

Looks like we're done. Now we just need to import these functions from the object and use them. The whole code:

```
case class Num(n:Int)
object Num {
  val incNum: Num => Num = n => Num(n.n + 1)
  val inc = (i: Int) => i + 1
}

implicit class Pipe(n:Num){
  def |(fn: (Num) => Num) = fn(n)
  def |(fn: (Int) => Int) = Num(fn(n.n))
}

import Num._
Num(0) | inc | inc         // Num(2)
Num(0) | incNum | incNum   // Num(2)
```

Comment: Just a hint, if you're using free functions a lot, then a general 'forward pipe' operator a'la F# can become useful: `implicit class ForwardPipe[T,U](arg : T) { def |>(f : T => U) = f(arg) }`

Comment: Thank you for your post. But I'm not sure I can use it. The first problem is that I have no idea how would I extend this solution to accept parameters (it's supposed to simulate "dot"; but maybe partially applied functions would do the trick?). Also I was hoping for a more general solution - the class I wanted to pimp has tens (maybe a hundread) methods, it would mean that I'd have to create wrappers for every single method...

Comment: @monnef Can you maybe update your question with an example that better suits your situation? Because I would love to help, but the question is what you're actually trying to accomplish with this pipe operator? Why do you even need it? `def | = n` provides no real value. If I understood the answer to these questions I could probably provide better help.

Comment: Also, you can use [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) to avoid helper class instantiation overhead.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy I have updated the question (I'm sorry it took so long).

Comment: @monnef Had a look at your update, sorry but I don't really see another solution. Your methods are built for fluid syntax, not DSLs: `println(echo("x").grep("x").wc().>>)`. Which, by the way, is a nice way of chaining methods. You're either going to have to redefine all function in Builder as `Builder => Builder` or forget the idea.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy Yeah, you're probably right, I can't avoid it (it might be doable via some bytecode library, but I think it wouldn't be easy to implement, especially when I have almost no experience with it). I can't change Builder (or any "command" class), so I suppose I'll have to create a wrapper class and in it methods like `echo(m:String) : MyBuilder => MyBuilder`?